# templated recursive data types

Tags: c++, templates, g++, c++11

I have a recursive data type like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct SomeType {
    std::map<T, SomeType<T>> mapping;
};

SomeType<int> foo;
```

This works fine, but replacing `std::map` with `std::unordered_map` results in a compile error due to an incomplete type. Am I (or gcc) making an error somewhere? or is this just part of the standard?

I would also like to have the internal container determined by a template parameter (like `std::stack` and `std::queue`), but I can't figure out a way to do it since that would require SomeType to already be defined.

Incomplete example:

```
template<typename T, typename C = std::map<T, SomeType<[???]>>>
struct SomeType {
    C mapping;
};

SomeType<int, [???]> foo;
```

I know this can be done with runtime indirection, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: The standard library container templates require that you instantiate them with complete types; all else is undefined behaviour. You have to live with that. You can use a pimpl solution to work around that, though.

Comment: @KerrekSB Is that so? Damn, I’ve regularly written n-ary trees whose nodes were implemented in terms of `std::vector<node> children`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Well, you have to make sure that at instantiation time the type is complete. That may be a subtle issue.

Comment: Funny enough, it *is* so. It just happens that the typical `vector` implementation works with incomplete types without modification -- you've been lucky all along.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your class is incomplete anywhere before the final `}` of its definition. So the `mapping` member is using incomplete type `SomeType` in its type's template arguments.

[The standard does not allow this, and it is pure luck that it works with some STL containers.](http://drdobbs.com/184403814)

Your second questions falls under the same answer -- it is illegal to do that in the first place.

Comment: Hmm. Unfortunately, I don’t understand the article’s argument about why `std::map<K, V>` with incomplete types can’t work in principle. Isn’t this very much like `std::vector<std::pair<K const, V>>`, which *can* work in principle (`std::pair<K const, V>` being incomplete)? Same goes for the other containers.

Comment: If this needs explanation, I suggest opening a chat room, it's not hard, just not suited for the comments section... Now, how do I explicitly open a chat room about this...

Comment: Let's chat here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9282/stl-with-incomplete-types

Answer (score 5):

You cannot define a template with recursive default parameters for obvious reasons. You also cannot instantiate standard library container templates on incomplete types, because the standard says so (otherwise it's undefined behaviour). The usual PIMPL idiom may help, though:

```
#include <map>
#include <memory>
template <typename T> class SomeType
{
    typedef std::map<T, SomeType<T>> map_type;
    typedef std::unique_ptr<map_type> map_ptr;
    map_ptr pimpl;
public:
    SomeType() : pimpl(new map_type) { }
};
```

Comment: The boost::container library provides alternatives for most STL types that allow recursive containers of incomplete types. It does not currently provide an unordered_map

Answer (score 3):

While you cannot use incomplete types with containers, you can do it with smart pointers.
And while you cannot create template types with undefined types parameters, you can use some tricks here:

```
template<typename T, template <typename U, typename V, typename... Args> class Container = std::unordered_map >
struct SomeType {
    Container<T, std::unique_ptr<SomeType> > mapping;
};
```

Comment: Is it possible to change the first line such that the default value for the Container would be std::vector?

Comment: @NielsLohmann, technically you can write `template<typename T, template <typename U, typename... Args> class Container = std::vector >`, but it would be inconsistent with  `std::unordered_map` than. Because map is _assosiative_ conrtainer and vector is just an array.

Comment: @NielsLohmann Hate to revive near-decade later, but out of curiousity - Is this [ObjectType definition](https://github.com/nlohmann/json/blob/199dea11b17c533721b26249e2dcaee6ca1d51d3/include/nlohmann/json_fwd.hpp#L39-L50)'s where this trick is used?

Comment: Yes, though I am still not 100% sure if this is allowed behavior - though it works on all compilers I've seen so far.