# Doubly self-recursive variant to hold JSON?

Tags: c++, variant

A JSON value can be a string, float, bool, null or an array or map of JSON values. Is there a way to model this recursive definition in a variant?

The forward declarations of the map and vector conflict as both want to know if the other is trivially destructible etc.

Is there a way round this with the STL vector and unordered_map classes?

```cpp
struct ValueVector;
struct ValueMap;
using Value = std::variant<
    std::monostate, 
    bool, 
    int64_t, 
    double, 
    std::string, 
    ValueVector,
    ValueMap
    >;
namespace std {
  template <> struct hash<ValueVector>
  {
    size_t operator()(const ValueVector& x) const;
  };
  template <> struct hash<ValueMap>
  {
    size_t operator()(const ValueMap& x) const;
  };
  template <> struct is_trivially_destructible<Value> {
    static constexpr bool value = false;
  };
}
struct ValueMap : std::unordered_map<std::string, Value> {};
struct ValueVector : std::vector<Value> {};
```

Comment: I think answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860503/templated-recursive-data-types

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you can't define a type that contains itself; this results in an incomplete type. You can, however, define a type that contains a *pointer* to itself.

```
struct Value {
  std::variant<
    std::monostate, 
    bool, 
    int64_t, 
    double, 
    std::string, 
    std::unordered_map<std::string, Value*>,
    std::vector<Value*>
  > v;
};
```